# How to take difference between current data and previous?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on Access 2010 table that contains the date, unit id, meter reading, with correction.  I want to take the daily reading of the meter by taking the current date and subtracting it with the previous.  Here is an example of the table I have:

```
InputDate | UnitID | MeterReading | Correction
--------- | ------ | ------------ | ----------
11/1/2016 | U1     | 41476        | 10000
11/1/2016 | U2     | 5991         | 10000
11/1/2016 | U3     | 164205       | 1000000
11/1/2016 | U4     | 11160        | 100000
11/2/2016 | U1     | 41490        | 10000
11/2/2016 | U2     | 5991         | 10000
11/2/2016 | U3     | 164205       | 1000000
11/2/2016 | U4     | 11169.3      | 100000
```

I've tried to do this a number of different ways.  The only way I got it to work is to make a query to split the table for each unit (e.g. U1, U2, etc.).  From that I would query that result and do this calculation:

```
(
([MeterReading]+[Correction]) - 
(DLookUp("MeterReading", "tblA", "[tblA].[InputDate] = #" & 
DateAdd("d",-1,[tblA].[InputDate]) & "#")+[Correction])
)
```

Then I would do another query to group all the data by date.

My question is if there is a more intuitive way to do this?  I've looked at ways to try doing SQL queries, nested queries, and just grouping by Unit_ID, but my calculation is off.  I think the DLookUp is not looking at the right unit when doing the calculation since there is multiple units on the same day.  Also, I get "Your query does not include the specified expression" when I try to group by InputDate and UnitID.  I'm new to SQL language so any help would be appreciated.

Sample output would be:

```
InputDate | UnitID | MeterRunTime
--------- | ------ | ------------
11/2/2016 | U1     | 14
11/2/2016 | U2     | 0
11/2/2016 | U3     | 0
11/2/2016 | U4     | 9.3
```

Comment: Can you give a sample output that you are expecting?

Comment: SQL sandbox http://rextester.com/GYVR98570 -- But I'm not sure what you mean by "I want to take the daily reading of the meter by taking the current date and subtracting it with the previous"; are you looking for the average daily meterreading (as in, the average usage per day)?

Comment: Added sample output @JyotiVinayPandey

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly the following should give you what you need.

```
SELECT tblA.InputDate, tblA.UnitID,
([tblA].[MeterReading]+[tblA].[Correction])-
([tblA_1].[MeterReading]+[tblA_1].[Correction]) AS MeterRunTime 
FROM tblA INNER JOIN tblA AS tblA_1 
ON (tblA.InputDate-1 = tblA_1.InputDate) AND (tblA.UnitID = tblA_1.UnitID);
```

Comment: For future readers and OP, please explain how your solution resolves OP's problem. Code alone is not helpful.

Comment: At first glance this will work providing a reading is taken every day - are readings taken at weekends, bank holidays, etc?  Maybe look for the maximum date that is less than the current date - which will give a reading since last reading rather than a daily reading.

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked for me!  The reading should be taken everyday, but there are times that there is a gap.  What would be the code to take the next available maximum date @Darren Bartrup-Cook?

Answer (score 0):

**Note**:  I'm a little rusty on the SQL so no doubt someone can improve upon this.

To return the next available date you'll need to find the maximum date that is less than the current date for each UnitID, and the current date for the same.

These two SQL statements will do that:

```
SELECT     MAX(tblA_1.InputDate) AS MaxDate
           ,tblA_1.UnitID
FROM        tblA tblA_1 INNER JOIN tblA tblA_2 ON tblA_1.UnitID = tblA_2.UnitID AND
                                                  tblA_1.InputDate < tblA_2.InputDate
GROUP BY    tblA_1.UnitID
```

---

```
SELECT      MAX(InputDate) AS CurrentDate
            ,UnitID
FROM        tblA
GROUP BY    UnitID
```

Next you'll need to include the Meter Reading + Correction to the previous results:

```
SELECT      MaxDate
            ,T1.UnitID
            ,MeterReading+Correction AS LastReading
FROM        tblA T1 INNER JOIN 
            (
            SELECT     MAX(tblA_1.InputDate) AS MaxDate
                       ,tblA_1.UnitID
            FROM        tblA tblA_1 INNER JOIN tblA tblA_2 ON tblA_1.UnitID = tblA_2.UnitID AND
                                                              tblA_1.InputDate < tblA_2.InputDate
            GROUP BY    tblA_1.UnitID
            ) T2 ON T1.InputDate = T2.MaxDate
GROUP BY    MaxDate
            ,T1.UnitID
            ,MeterReading+Correction
```

---

```
SELECT      CurrentDate
            ,T4.UnitID
            ,MeterReading+Correction AS CurrentReading  
FROM        tblA T3 INNER JOIN
            (
            SELECT      MAX(InputDate) AS CurrentDate
                        ,UnitID
            FROM        tblA
            GROUP BY    UnitID
            ) T4 ON T3.InputDate = T4.CurrentDate AND T3.UnitID = T4.UnitID
GROUP BY    CurrentDate
            ,T4.UnitID
            ,MeterReading+Correction
```

Finally you can stick the whole lot together to give your final result:

```
SELECT  CurrentDate
        ,MaxDate
        ,T1.UnitID
        ,LastReading
        ,CurrentReading
        ,CurrentReading - LastReading AS FinalReading
FROM
        (
        SELECT      MaxDate
                    ,T1.UnitID
                    ,MeterReading+Correction AS LastReading
        FROM        tblA T1 INNER JOIN 
                        (
                            SELECT     MAX(tblA_1.InputDate) AS MaxDate
                                        ,tblA_1.UnitID
                            FROM        tblA tblA_1 INNER JOIN tblA tblA_2 ON tblA_1.UnitID = tblA_2.UnitID AND
                                                               tblA_1.InputDate < tblA_2.InputDate
                            GROUP BY    tblA_1.UnitID
                        ) T2 ON T1.InputDate = T2.MaxDate
        GROUP BY    MaxDate
                    ,T1.UnitID
                    ,MeterReading+Correction
        )  T5
        INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT      CurrentDate
                    ,T4.UnitID
                    ,MeterReading+Correction AS CurrentReading  
        FROM        tblA T3 INNER JOIN
                        (
                            SELECT      MAX(InputDate) AS CurrentDate
                                        ,UnitID
                            FROM        tblA
                            GROUP BY    UnitID
                        ) T4 ON T3.InputDate = T4.CurrentDate AND T3.UnitID = T4.UnitID
        GROUP BY    CurrentDate
                    ,T4.UnitID
                    ,MeterReading+Correction
        ) T6 ON T5.UnitID = T6.UnitID
```

[image]

As you can see, changing the dates makes no difference to the final query output:
[image]